# how to remove the shell menu entry for "ununstall with revo uninstaller"

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

my right click menu has become a mess, lot of programs, and i want to remove some of those right click items, how to remove the shell menu entry for "ununstall with revo uninstaller", becoz i never use this feature. so help please?

Answer (score 1):

The freeware utilities [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) and [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) from [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/index.html) allow some control over these menus.